# @Order with different values in two Lists

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Below is my requirement with a simple example:

```
public interface Animal {}

@Component
@Order(1)
public class Hippo implements Animal{}

@Component
@Order(2)
public class Crocodile implements Animal{}
```

I want to inject them into two `List`'s with different orders. eg `landAnimals` should have Hippo in the first index and Crocodile in the second index while `waterAnimals` should have Crocodile in the first index and Hippo in the second index.

```
@Autowired
private List<Animal> landAnimals; // 0-Hippo & 1-Crocodile (achieved with @Order)

@Autowired
private List<Animal> waterAnimals; // 0-Crocodile & 1-Hippo (not achieved)
```

@Order, can we change it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do dynamically using `@Order`.

**Note:** I think that you don't need to create two different lists. Inject a single list and reverse accordingly when required.

You can call `Collections.reverse()` to reverse the list for your requirement.

Example :

```
@Autowired
private List<Animal> landAnimals;

public void showOrderList() {
   Collections.reverse(animals);
   for (Animal animal : animals) {
      // do some operation..
   }
}
```

Comment: I need to inject them in different Beans, so this is something needs to be handled at framework level. Solution that I could think of is to prepare these Lists explicitly with "@"Bean in "@"Configuration class and then inject them.
Changing "@"Order value based on condition doesn't look possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is use `PostConstruct`, you can change the order in there like below

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    waterAnimals.sort(AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.INSTANCE.reversed());
}
```

Comment: Reversing may not solve it fully. In future I may have more beans and the order could be changed. Basically I need more flexibility to define the order so that in future I am not tied to a single(including reverse) order.

Comment: @Hamid you can write your own comparator, reverse just for this situation.

Comment: Careful: `sort` modifies the list (and in this case a singleton bean), so any other component that uses the list/bean will have the same order.

Comment: @RoToRa you are wrong, other components that use this bean/list order not change, you can try it

Comment: You are saying the collections are injected as prototypes (a separate instance for each request) instead of a singleton (a single instance for all requests), which is the default? Can you show me the documentation on that?

Comment: @RoToRa Spring not holding a list of these two beans, spring keeps the beans separately, this beans will be added to the list when you autowire the list. Every component has its own list and order.

Comment: OK. Good to know. However I'd still love to see some documentation on that point.

Comment: You can search, I didn't read it from docs, I try it, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Put the order into the interface:

```
public interface Animal {
   int getLandOrder();
   int getWaterOrder();
}
```

Create a service bean that provides the differently sorted lists.

```
@Service
public class AnimalService {

    private final List<Animals> landAnimals;
    private final List<Animals> waterAnimals;

    // BTW, don't use field injection 
    public AnimalService(List<Animal> animals) {
       // Create copies of the list, because they are sorted in place
       landAnimals = new ArrayList<>(animals);
       landAnimals.sort(Comparator.comparing(Animal::getLandOrder));

       waterAnimals = new ArrayList<>(animals);
       waterAnimals.sort(Comparator.comparing(Animal::getWaterOrder));
    }
    
    public List<Animal> getLandAnimals() {
      return landAnimals;
    }

    public List<Animal> getWaterAnimals() {
      return waterAnimals;
    }
}
```

Now inject `AnimalService` where you need a list, and use the getters.